# How to make home button hug the left side of the action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock and have set an icon using `android:logo` in my theme. I'd like for the icon to be flush with the left side of the screen, but it always has 6px of spacing (measured using the hierarchy viewer). I've highlighted in red the part of the icon that I can't get rid of. If I set `DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP` for the action bar, then the up affordance is shown as in the second image with no additional spacing.

I assume the spacing is there to keep the icon in the same place regardless of whether the up arrow present. I'm never going to show the up arrow, so I rather have the icon flush on the left.

[image: ActionBar]

[image: ActionBar with up affordance]

Comment: fwiw all of the google apps that leverage the actionbar have the same blank space on their home activities; gmail, play, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set customView  like this:

actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.customActionBarLayout)

and create  your own layout just as you like it

Comment: I'm already using a custom view for the middle portion of the action bar. I guess I was hoping I could get away with using the build-in home button.

Comment: you can stretch the custom view also to include the logo portion